# Сделать более быструю анимацию внутри другой анимации на Vue

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть вот такой переход (как на первой гифке), сделанный с помощью Vue.js (v-if и т.п.). Мне нужно, чтобы вот эта миниатюра картинки исчезала быстрее чем идет основной переход (т.к. при более узком экране, как я понял, она не дает выехать шторке и анимация становится рваной как на второй гифке). Пробовал обернуть картинку в отдельный , с более короткой анимацией, не вышло. Думал еще с помощью jQuery сделать исчезновение, но хочется на вью...

Первая гифкка (без глюков)

[image: первая гифка]

Вторая гифка (с глюками)

[image: вторая гифка]

Сам сайт:
http://featherdesign.realnost.club/

Answer (score 0):

IMHO.

Судя по первой гифке, если обратить внимание на блок с текстом справа, то видно, что при анимации текст сжимается, соответственно анимация исчезновения блока сделана не изменением left/margin-left + width, а банальным transform: scaleX.

Попробуйте изменить. Потому что глюки появляются при переносе текста и других элементов разметки при изменении размеров родительского блока (белого).

Comment: В случае использования transform: scale элементы не изменяют своего положения и размеров относительно родительского элемента. Вот.

Comment: нене, у меня анимация - банальный fade как здесь [vue.org](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0)
сдвиг происходит за счет анимации шторки